# Jira rest api error Invalid request payload when I update project

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api

Jira error when I creating and updating project in php jira rest client

This is updating project code

```
function updateProject()
    {
        try {
            $p = new Project();
            $p->setName('test-project123456')
                ->setProjectTypeKey('software')
                ->setProjectTemplateKey('com.atlassian.jira-software-project-templates:jira-software-project-management')
                ->setDescription('Updated Example Project description')
                ->setLeadAccountId('712020:11db78e0-5882-4547-acf1-9baf0250055e')
                ->setUrl('http://local11-jira.atlassian.net')
                ->setAssigneeType('UNASSIGNED')
            ;
            $proj = new ProjectService();
            $pj = $proj->updateProject($p,'TP');
            var_dump($pj);
        } catch (JiraRestApi\JiraException $e) {
            print('Error Occured! ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And when I run this code, I get this error :"Invalid request payload. Refer to the REST API documentation and try again."